# Insert dataframe cell value (list) to mysql multiple columns Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with Data-frames in Python and trying to insert data in MySQL Database. I know I can use `df.to_sql` to insert dataframe into sql but in my case, I've a list in one of the cells of dataframe and I've to insert that list into multiple columns of table in database.

Here is my dataframe:

```
UserId UserName Address Res
1      User1    Add1    [1,2,3...36]
2      User2    Add2    [1,2,3...36]
```

This is my database table structure:

```
UserId UserName Address Res1 Res2 Res3... Res36
```

Now I'm stuck here that how can I insert `Res` data into multiple columns in an efficient way? List data is in sequence with column names so I don't have to worry about correct col name/ data.

Any guesses??

Comment: Did you try storing list items to string variables?

Comment: No, I didn't.. store them as a separate string variable??

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Are you just asking how to split the sequences into their own columns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2):

You can split your list column to multiple columns and then use `df.to_sql` on the new dataframe:

```
In [971]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[971]: 
   UserId UserName Address           Res
0       1    User1    Add1  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1       2    User2    Add2  [2, 3, 4, 5]

In [973]: pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df['Res'].values.tolist())], axis=1).drop('Res', 1)                                                                                                                   
Out[973]: 
   UserId UserName Address  0  1  2  3
0       1    User1    Add1  1  2  3  4
1       2    User2    Add2  2  3  4  5
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns